# end of a file using awk in Unix

Tags: unix, awk

I have a problem using awk. Print, from every file given as a parameter, the number of line that has the length at least 10. Also, print the content of that line(s), except the fist 10 characters. At the end of the analysis of a file print the name of the file and the number of lines printed.

This is what I've done so far:

```
{
if(length($0)>10)
{
 print "The number of line is:" FNR
 print "The content of the line is:" substr($0,10)
 s=s+1
}
x= wc -l //number of lines of file
if(FNR > x) //this is supposed to show when the file is over but it's not working
{           //I also tried if (FNR == 1) - which means new file
 print "This was the analysis of the file:" FILENAME
 print "The number of lines with characters >10 are:" s
}
}
```

This prints the name of the file and the number of lines after every line that has at least 10 characters but I want something like this:

```
print "The number of line is:" 1
print "The content of the line is:" dkhflaksfdas
print "The number of line is:" 3
print "The content of the line is:" asdfdassaf
print "This was the analysis of the file:" awk.txt
print "The number of lines with characters >10 are:" 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
length($0) >= 10 {                             
    print "The number of line is:",FNR 
    print "The content of the line is:",substr($0,11)
    count++                                              
}
ENDFILE {                        
    print "This was the analysis of the file:",FILENAME
    print "The number of lines with characters >= 10 are:",count
    count = 0
}
```

Save it as `script.awk` and run like `awk -f script.awk file1 file2 file3`.

Notes:

- For line length the requirement `the number of lines that has the length at least 10` should be `>=10`.
- `except the fist 10 characters` means you want to start from the 11th with `substr($0,11)`.
- The conditional `length($0) >= 10` should be done outside the block.
- You need to use the special `ENDFILE` block to print the analysis at the end of each file.
- You need to reset the `count` and the end of each file otherwise you will get a running total across all the files.

Comment: +1 for good solution. For the OP - just be aware that ENDFILE is only available in recent releases of GNU awk, not in any other awk. If you don't have and can't get gawk (try - it's well worth it), you need to duplicate the code in both FNR==1 and END blocks or build up an array to print in the END section.